# Return of value on keyup with Jquery

Tags: jquery, keyup

With this code, the console display "ReferenceError: myVar is not defined".
If I initialize the variable before the function, it value doesn't change after.
What's wrong ?

Thank's to help me !

```
$('#origVal').keyup(function ()
{
    myVar = $('#origVal').val();
});
console.log(myVar);
```

**UPDATE**

I try to recover the text that was entered in an input with keyup.
The goal is to give to dat.gui the contents recovered to display it in 3D with three.js. I know maybe I'm wrong with the way to do that...

```
<body>
    <input type='text' id='origVal'>
    <script>
        var myVar = "";
        $('#origVal').keyup(function ()
        {
            myVar = $('#origVal').val();
        });
        document.write(myVar); //It doesn't work !
        var guis = {
            TextGeometry : function( mesh )
            {
            var data = {
            text : myVar, //It doesn't work !
         ...
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: make the myVar global

Comment: `var myVar ;
$('#origVal').keyup(function ()
{
    myVar = $('#origVal').val();
});
console.log(myVar);` try like this

Comment: Thank's for your help, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: try the answer i provided i when you declare the var it should be `var myVar = "";`

Comment: I tried this also, but it doesn't work.

Comment: then check the answer i provided

Comment: check this fiddle i hope this what you wanted https://jsfiddle.net/bLd0xoyf/

Comment: Thank's, I am going to check that.

Comment: Your code run, but it's not what I want. It's necessary for me to have document.write(myVar) outside a function.

Comment: @Nadir document.write will run as soon as it possibly can after the page loads.  At this stage, the variable myVar is either undefined or empty.  The `document.write` call isn't going to wait for input to then write something.  Can you post what it is you are trying to do, and why the document.write needs to run as soon as the page loads and not as part of a function?

Comment: @gabe3886 thank's you.
I'm going to update my post.

Answer (score 0):

Put a keyword `val` in front of `myVar` if you did not define it already.

Comment: this will make the console.log return undefined

Comment: Yes, you are right, he should define var myVar before the function, and that way make it global :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your console.log(myVar) inside the function. Even though you are declaring a global variable, it might not be in its scope for some reason, and is throwing an error. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thank's for your help, but I want use the variable after the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myVar = "";
        $('#origVal').keyup(function () {
            myVar = $('#origVal').val();
            console.log(myVar);
        });


    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <input id="origVal" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank's for your help, but I want use the variable after the function.

Comment: I explained that in my first post. Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myVar = "";
$('#origVal').keyup(function() {
    myVar1 = $(this).val();
    func(myVar1)
});


function func(myVar){
console.log(myVar);
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bLd0xoyf/1/)

try this way

Comment: It doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ok your code run with console.log, but if I want to replace the console.log by document.write ?

Comment: then append it to the body

Answer (score 0):

I don't usually recommend saving to the window, but one way you could accomplish this and use the value afterwards is save it to the window. So:

```
 $('#origVal').keyup(function () {
        myVar = $('#origVal').val();
        window["window_myVar"] = myVar;
 });

  console.log(window["window_myVar"]);
```

That will spit out the value and instead of console.log, you could do document.write or whatever you were trying to do with the variable. Note that I appended "window_" before the variable. I do that whenever I use this to make sure that the variable I am created is not overwriting another variable on the window (make it unique). Hope this helps.